# How do I remove partial duplicates from an unsorted list in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a large list

```
[[1,.., ..],[2,...,...],[5,...,...],[1,...,...]]
```

I need to remove all elements that have the same first value. (keep only once)

How to do it most efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a `set` of the first values seen so far, and only keep sublists if their first value isn't in the set.

Because `set.add` always returns `None`, `keys.add(sublist[0]) or sublist` is the same as `None or sublist` which is the same as `sublist`, so it doesn't affect what gets kept in the list, while allowing you to add values to the set inside a list comprehension.

```
keys = set()
biglist = [keys.add(sublist[0]) or sublist 
              for sublist in biglist 
                  if sublist[0] not in keys]
del keys # if you don't need it any more
```

Comment: wow, that's quite good answer, and it works. it took me a few mins to figure it out though. thanks for the explanation

Comment: It is super quick!

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence of the list does not matter, you can try this:

```
dict([(sublist[0], sublist) for sublist in biglist]).values()
```

or

```
dict([(sublist[0], sublist) for sublist in reversed(biglist)]).values()
```

The difference is that the second one returns the first list for the same first value, the other one does oppositely.